# Respond with multiple content types to a single request

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to respond to a single GET request with both the requested document and a JSON object from the http.Server request callback?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to use the same handler to return *either* JSON *or* HTML dependent on some condition (like a passed parameter indicating which type to return), or do you actually want to return two responses for one request?

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to give two different HTTP `Content-Type`s from the same page, that is not possible due to limitations in the protocol. You could however, create another iFrame on the page, and have the main frame serve one type, and the iFrame serve the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two different types in a single response, I think that a [Multi-Part MIME](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) response is your best bet.